# JavaScript code not working (event does not fire) in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have written code that calculates the price for a reservation. This code works for Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc. But it does not work in IE (10). It simply does not fire because even the alert at the very start doesn't show. I have allowed DirectX and also have set security to the lowest possible option in the security options. I have no idea what reason this might have.

To test it live, fill in the first page of the form and on the second page, the script should be fired once you selected an arrival date and departure date: https://www.vakantiehuislesforges.com/reserveren-stap1/

This is the event to trigger it:

```
<input type="text" name="aankomstdatum" id="aankomstdatum" onchange="aankomstdatumInput();berekenPrijs()">
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
var aankomstDatumDate;
var vertrekDatumDate;
var spans;
var totaalPersonen;

alert("IE test");

//Get arrival date from datepicker + aantal kinderen & volwassenen
function aankomstdatumInput() {
var aankomstDatum = document.getElementById("aankomstdatum").value;
//alert(aankomstDatum);
document.getElementById("aankomst").innerHTML = aankomstDatum;
var parts = aankomstDatum.split('-');
aankomstDatumDate = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
//alert(aankomstDatumDate);
document.getElementById("aankomstDate").innerHTML = aankomstDatumDate;
//get aantal kinderen en volwassenen
spans = document.querySelectorAll('#aantallen span');
totaalPersonen = Array.from(spans).reduce((sum, spanElm) => sum + Number(spanElm.textContent), 0);
//alert(totaalPersonen);
}

//Get departure date from datepicker
function vertrekdatumInput() {
vertrekDatum = document.getElementById("vertrekdatum").value;
//alert(vertrekDatum);
document.getElementById("vertrek").innerHTML = vertrekDatum;
var parts2 = vertrekDatum.split('-');
vertrekDatumDate = new Date(parts2[2],parts2[1]-1,parts2[0]);
document.getElementById("vertrekDate").innerHTML = vertrekDatumDate;
}

//fire function onchange and get the arrival date and departure date and make the array
function berekenPrijs() {
//var aankomst = new Date("November 25, 2017");
//var vertrek = new Date("December 2, 2017");
//alert(aankomstDatumDate);
//alert(vertrekDatumDate);
//alert(aankomst);
var maand = aankomstDatumDate.getMonth();
var verblijfDagen = [];
var day = 1000*60*60*24;
var diff = (vertrekDatumDate.getTime()- aankomstDatumDate.getTime())/day;

//calculate all seperate days from arrival date to departure date and put them in an array   
for(var i=0;i<=diff; i++)
{
   var xx = aankomstDatumDate.getTime()+day*i;
   var yy = new Date(xx);
   var zz = (yy.getDate()+"-"+(yy.getMonth()+1)+"-"+yy.getFullYear());
   var parts = zz.split('-');
   var zzDate = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
   //check if this date is a saturday and in the correct Date structure && zzDate mag niet gelijk zijn aan vertrekdatum of laatst
   if(zzDate.getDay() === 0) verblijfDagen.push(zzDate);
   //alert(verblijfDagen);
}
//check if all the days are in the array
//alert (verblijfDagen);

//declare the period of the different seasons and the daily cost rate during this season 
var December2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,12-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,12-1,31), costRate: 550};
var November2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,11-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,11-1,30), costRate: 550};
var Oktober2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,10-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,10-1,31), costRate: 690};
var September2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,9-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,9-1,30), costRate: 1190};
var Augustus2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,8-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,8-1,31), costRate: 1690};
var Juli2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,7-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,7-1,31), costRate: 1690};
var Juni2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,6-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,6-1,30), costRate: 1190};
var MeiEind2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,5-1,15), endDate: new Date(2019,5-1,31), costRate: 1190};
var MeiBegin2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,5-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,-1,14), costRate: 840};
var April2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,4-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,4-1,30), costRate: 750};
var Maart2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,3-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,3-1,31), costRate: 550};
var Februari2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,2-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,2-1,30), costRate: 550};
var Januari2019 = {startDate: new Date(2019,1-1,1), endDate: new Date(2019,1-1,31), costRate: 550};
var December2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,12-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,12-1,31), costRate: 550};
var November2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,11-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,11-1,30), costRate: 550};
var Oktober2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,10-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,10-1,31), costRate: 690};
var September2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,9-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,9-1,30), costRate: 1190};
var Augustus2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,8-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,8-1,31), costRate: 1690};
var Juli2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,7-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,7-1,31), costRate: 1690};
var Juni2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,6-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,6-1,30), costRate: 1190};
var MeiEind2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,5-1,15), endDate: new Date(2018,5-1,31), costRate: 1190};
var MeiBegin2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,5-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,-1,14), costRate: 840};
var April2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,4-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,4-1,30), costRate: 750};
var Maart2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,3-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,3-1,31), costRate: 550};
var Februari2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,2-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,2-1,30), costRate: 550};
var Januari2018 = {startDate: new Date(2018,1-1,1), endDate: new Date(2018,1-1,31), costRate: 550};
var December2017 = {startDate: new Date(2017,12-1,1), endDate: new Date(2017,12-1,31), costRate: 550};
var November2017 = {startDate: new Date(2017,11-1,1), endDate: new Date(2017,11-1,30), costRate: 550};
var allSeasons = [November2017, December2017, Januari2018, Februari2018, Maart2018, April2018, MeiBegin2018, MeiEind2018, Juni2018, Juli2018, Augustus2018, September2018, Oktober2018, November2018, December2018, Januari2019, Februari2019, Maart2019, April2019, MeiBegin2019, MeiEind2019, Juni2019, Juli2019, Augustus2019, September2019, Oktober2019, November2019, December2019];
//check if this date is in the correct Date structure
//alert(November2017.startDate instanceof Date);
//check if the date is correct
//alert (November2017.startDate);

var totalPrice = 0;
for (var u = 0; u < verblijfDagen.length; u++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < allSeasons.length; j++) {
    if (verblijfDagen[u] >= allSeasons[j].startDate && verblijfDagen[u] <= allSeasons[j].endDate) {
      //Add costRate of this date to totalPrice
      totalPrice = totalPrice + allSeasons[j].costRate;
    }
  }
}

var totalPriceFinal = totalPrice + (totaalPersonen*10);
var totalVoorschot = totalPriceFinal/100*50;
var totalRestBedrag = totalPriceFinal/100*50;
//alert (totalVoorschot);
//alert (totalRestbedrag);

document.getElementById("totaalPrijsLabel").innerHTML = totalPriceFinal;
document.getElementById("totaalPrijs").value = totalPriceFinal;
document.getElementById("totaalVoorschot").value = totalVoorschot;
document.getElementById("totaalRestbedrag").value = totalRestbedrag;
};
```

Comment: What is `endDate: new Date(2018,-1,14)`?   Is it intended to have `,-1,`?

Comment: More importantly, how on earth do we know what's "does not work"? An error? An incorrect result?

Comment: It simply does not do anything. I added a test alert that should be triggered at page load and even that isnt showing. The -1 is intented.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your `ECMA 6 arrow` is not supported on IE10, on this line:

```
Array.from(spans).reduce((sum, spanElm) => sum + Number(spanElm.textContent), 0);
```

Comment: But would that explain why even the test alert doesnt work since that is supposed to trigger as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes. When IE fires that code, it faces "Syntax Error" so the whole script won't run.